# http radio-Attribut using angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have the following code

```
 <div>Yes or no?</div>
 <input type="radio" id="Nein" name="isUsedFor [(ngValue)]="isNotUsedFor" [(ngModel)]="isNotUsedFor">
 <label for="no">Nein</label><br>
 <input type="radio" id="Ja" name="isUsedFor" [(ngValue)]="isUsedFor" [(ngModel)]="isUsedFor">
 <label for="yes">Ja</label>
 </div>
```

My problem is, when I click on **Nein**, then **Ja** will be selected and not the **Nein**, and when I click on **Ja** then the **Nein** will be selected.
[image]

Here for example I have clicked on **Nein** and **Ja** will be selected and when I submit, then **Ja** will be submitted.
Do you have a idea to solve my inconvenience?
Thank you in advance.

Here is my `.ts` file:

```
  public isNotUsedFor: string = "Nein";
  public isUsedFor: string = "Ja";
```

Answer (score 1):

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/radio-buttons-xpolgz?file=app/app.component.ts)

You should use one model for both input and give value to input elements.

```
 <div>Yes or no?</div>
 <input type="radio" id="Nein" name="isUsedFor" value="Nein" [(ngModel)]="isUsedFor"/>
 <label for="no">Nein</label><br>
 <input type="radio" id="Ja" name="isUsedFor" value="Ja" [(ngModel)]="isUsedFor"/>
 <label for="yes">Ja</label>

<br>
 {{isUsedFor}}
```

in component

```
isUsedFor: string = "Ja";
```

Comment: I would prefer, to remove the *default-value* and write only `isUserFor: string;` to the component without declaration, so the *default-value* is nothing and not "Ja".

Comment: Thank you very much :-) you saved my day. but i'll let the default-value (but this time isUsedFor: string = "Nein") because the most selected choice will be "Nein" and that can make the application easier.